# How can I improve the security around my house and prevent theft?

Tags: security

My family and I moved to a new residential area. The environment is neither guarded nor gated, therefore security matters are concerning to us e.g. break-ins, theft, kidnapping, etc.

Since we moved in, our fence was often broken anonymously. We use a steel and aluminium fence. Therefore we set up CCTV cameras around the house, but recently the CCTV cameras were stolen also. This had made us very upset because the damage was costly.

I would like some suggestions on how to improve the quality of security. Moving again is not an option.

Comment: What country do you live in?  Is an alarm system an option?

Comment: Yes we do have an alarm system. But it did not link with the CCTV cameras. Perhaps I need to link the alarm system with my CCTV cameras? Before we install the CCTV cameras, break ins were happening. But now the thief are stealing CCTV cameras instead of break ins *sigh* It was like giving something to entertain the thief. I cannot think of a way to put this to an end.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: have nothing of value in the house worth stealing. This is easier to do than you might think. No reason to keep anything particularly valuable in a house that is being targeted for break-ins. Anything valuable you cannot bear to remove from the house should be hidden in a non-obvious location (think creatively). Now, if someone breaks into your house when you're not there, they don't get anything. No big deal. Eventually word will get around in the criminal underground and hooligans will stop breaking into your house.

Step 2: get a big scary dog and a handgun. Train the dog to bark at people approaching the house and bite on command, and carry the gun on your person while you are at home. Now, if someone breaks into your house while you're there your dog will bite them and/or you can shoot them (ignore whichever piece of advice offends you if you are not a dog person or a gun person). However kidnapping is an extremely serious matter and I urge you not to discount any potentially useful options.

Comment: Do look up the laws concerning what you are allowed to do to a intruder to defend your property. Some jurisdictions don't like lethal force being used even to defend your TV.

Comment: Excellent point, but in a country like Malaysia it may be more based on the proclivities and corruption level in the local police department than the law itself. Figure out what the police will reasonably permit you to do and prepare to go no further.